# Android Osmdroid : How to implement IArchiveFile interface for read pbf files using OSM binary library

Tags: java, android, maps, osmdroid

I am developing an android app that shows offline maps of my whole country. I use the offline maps gernerated in osm and compressed with Google Protocol Buffer, the result is a file with osm.pbf extension.

My goal is to pass this file to osmdroid. In my research i founded litle bit information about that topic. I founded that there is a library [osm-binary](https://github.com/scrosby/OSM-binary) written in Java that reads and parse nodes, relations and ways from pbf format files. I say, THAT'S THE WAY!!!.

So, this is my question, How to use the result of osm-binary with in the IArchiFile interface in the osmdroid library?

Answer (score 1):

Well IArchiveFile is used to load bitmap tiles from archive. But your pbf file contains  raw openstreetmap data (nodes, ways and relations). So you would need to load the data and render them into bitmap (handle caching and so on) and that is a huge amount of work.

You should render the tiles on the server and use them as offline source. Please check documentation here: https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/Offline-Map-Tiles.html

I have been using [TileMill](https://github.com/tilemill-project/tilemill) for styling and rendering OSM data for one of my projects. Output can be xyz.mbiles archive and osmdroid supports those. But whole setup is nontrivial (backend for data processing and tile rendering) and there may be some less difficult approach which suits your needs.